# Need help understanding JAudioTagger, Tag Mapping

Tags: java, metadata, jaudiotagger

I am using the JAudioTagger Library to read the metadata from my music files. I was able to retrieve information but looking over the Tag Mapping Spec http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/tagmapping.html. I am trying to retrieve the MusicBrainz Recording ID and have no idea how to choose that specific one. The MP3 file is either ID3v23 or v24, not sure which one. I tried searching with `UFID` and `MUSICBRAINZ_TRACK_ID`.

```
File file = new File("09 Bleeding Out.mp3");

    AudioFile mp3 = null;
    try {
        mp3 = AudioFileIO.read(file);
    } catch (CannotReadException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TagException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ReadOnlyFileException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidAudioFrameException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Tag tag = mp3.getTag();
    System.out.println(tag.getFirst("UFID"));
    Iterator<TagField> it = tag.getFields();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(it.next());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `FieldKey.MUSICBRAINZ_TRACK_ID` - this is the recording ID. It maps to `UFID:http://musicbrainz.org` i.e. a field giving the UFID for this track as per MusicBrainz.

An alternative may be to use `TXXX:MusicBrainz Recording Id`.

Finally, note that this field is not that commonly found in files.